# get Hibernate Entity field with column name

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I was looking arround for this, but I couldn´t find a right answer.

I´m trying to get any field from an entity based on it´s column name.

Like a generic get, in which it receives a `String columnName` and returns an `Object field` that represents the Class field which is mapped by that columnName by Hibernate.

For example

```
    @Table(name="ENTITY_EXAMPLE")
    public class EntityExample{

       @Column(name="COL_NAME")
       private String name;

       @Column(name="COL_SURNAME")
       private String surname;

       public EntityExample(String name, String surname){
          this.name=name;
          this.surname=surname;
       }

        //getters and setters

       public Object getField(String columnName){

          Object field=//some way to map the columnName with the field;
          return field;
       }
}

public main(String[] args){

   EntityExample example=new EntityExample("John", "Doe");

   String exampleName=(String) example.getField("COL_NAME");
   String exampleSurname=(String) example.getField("COL_SURNAME");

  System.out.println("NAME: "+ exampleName+ ", SURNAME: "+exampleSurname);
}
```

and that main when runs should print:

```
NAME: John, SURNAME: Doe
```

The way I´m doing now is with ifs that checks if the parameter is equal to each annotated column and inside returns the field if equals,  but it should be a propper way to do that.

way I'm doing now:

```
public Object getField(String columnName){

   if(columnName.equals("COL_NAME")){
    return name;
   }
   if(columnName.equals("COL_SURNAME")){
    return surname;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the way you're doing it, is the only way. With the exception being, to use a switch statement instead of multiple if statements:

```
switch (columnName) {
            case 1:  columnName = "COL_NAME";
                     return this.name;
                     break;
            case 2:  columnName= "COL_SURNAME";
                     return this.surname;
                     break;
            default: columnName= "COL_BLAHBLAH";
                     return this.blahblhblah;
                     break;
        }
```

The only possible way to what you want (and this is a big stretch), is if you did something along the lines of:

```
public Object getField(String columnName){

          Object field= (Object)columnName; 
          return field;
       }
```

Note: You would need to pass in the object name (aka: name,surname) and not the column name.

But I honestly don't think this is going to work. Regardless, you would need to cast a string as an object in such a way that the compiler would know how to handle the casting properly (don't think it's possible).

Good luck either way. Maybe someone else will have more ideas.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll keep doing the same way until some answer come up, I thought it might be a better way to do that. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can , of course, use reflection to go through the fields of your entity, looking for which one has the `@Column` annotation with the corresponding name. However, many people will tell you that Reflection is slow.

What we did to accomplish this was to create a set of public static integer constants for each of the columns. Thus in your entity you would have the following:

```
public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_SURNAME = 2;
```

and in the Entity you also have a `getFieldValue` method as follows:

```
public Object getFieldValue(int fieldNo) {
    switch (fieldNo) {
        case COL_NAME:
            return this.name;
        case COL_SURNAME:
            return this.surname;
        default:
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Field Number: " + fieldNo);
    }
}
```

and you would use these to get fields values as follows:

```
String name = entityExample.getFieldValue(EntityExample.COL_NAME);
```

Of course, the problem you have now is maintaining both the list of constants and the switch cases when columns are added/removed/renamed. We get round this by using a script to generate both the constants and the method. You could also use Java's annotation processing to generate the same code.